# Session id should be regenerated after logging in

Tags: java

I have one requirement in which session id should invalidate after login and new session id should regenerate,

like this Pre-cookie and Post Cookie should not be same and Post cookie should be validate at server side.

I used this piece of code to invalidating the session :

```
req.getSession(false).invalidate(); 
req.getSession(true);
```

I am able to change the session id but it will logout. I tested same scenario using burp tool suite. I got these results:

While Login :

```
Cookie: navi=1-1-0-; SOSESSIONID=pxtc730f4259; SSO_ID=4419102748602016135; CSSOSESSIONID=20971435-a754-43d5-aa56-7083e2dba55b; JSESSIONID=jpofvmzlses2
Connection: close
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

After Login :

```
Cookie: SSO_ID=; navi=1-1-0-; SOSESSIONID=ssnuqpjpal2i; SSO_ID=323568307087821651; CSSOSESSIONID=20971435-a754-43d5-aa56-7083e2dba55b; JSESSIONID=jpofvmzlses2
Connection: close
```

But After that if I am clicking anything in GUI, I am redirecting to Login Page.

Can you please help me how to regenerate session id after login so that same id should not continue through out ?

Comment: Why? It's still the same session. The only difference after logging in is that now it is authenticated, has a Subject, a Principal, roles, etc.

Comment: How do yo handle login? You probably use the session. If you invalidate it you need to copy that information from the old session to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

To handle [session fixation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation), you can invalidate the session and start new session before login the user.

Once you take username and password, invalidate the old session and create new session and then check for login credentials, This should solve the issue.